# Prisma: Getting records that have X or more related records

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I have the following prisma schema:

```
model TtnMapperDatapoint {
    id                   Int                @id
    deviceGPSDatapoint   DeviceGPSDatapoint @relation(fields: [deviceGPSDatapointId], references: [id])
    deviceGPSDatapointId Int
    ...
}

model DeviceGPSDatapoint {
    id                  Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
    latitude            Float
    longitude           Float
    ttnMapperDatapoints TtnMapperDatapoint[]
    ...
}
```

Using TypeScript, I want to get all records of DeviceGPSDatapoint that have X or more associated records of TtnMapperDatapoint. Searching online, I couldn't really find anything save Prisma's own [aggregate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing) feature, but that doesn't seem to exactly do what I intend to do.

I found code like

```
prisma.user.findMany({ where: {
  posts: { none: {} }
}})
```

but as far as I could see, only `none` and `some` are supported in `findMany` queries.

The SQL query I'm expecting would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
            FROM "DeviceGPSDatapoint"
            WHERE (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM "TtnMapperDatapoint"
                WHERE "DeviceGPSDatapoint".id = "TtnMapperDatapoint"."deviceGPSDatapointId"
            ) >= 3;
```

Comment: Could you add the expected sql query that you expect to get executed in postgres?